# Check for a Substring after a particular occurrence of string which is separated by dots

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a string with dots. I want to get a particular substring after occurrence of word

> entity

that is for example

```
String givenStr = "com.web.rit.entity.TestName.create";
output - TestName

String givenStr = "com.web.rit.entity.TestName2.update";
output - TestName2
```

So as explained above I have to extract substring after the string **entity** from the given string. Can anyone please help? (I am using java to do it).

Comment: What did you tried ? You can use `replace` method ?

Comment: Hi @Elikill58, I thought I will split it using dots which will give me an array of strings and then run a loop through the array to check for the occurrence of the "entity" word and then take the next string to that from the array.

Comment: Yes sorry i didn't well understand your question. I'm writing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```java
String givenStr = "com.web.rit.entity.TestName.create"; // begin str
String wording = "entity"; // looking for begin
String[] splitted = givenStr.split("\\."); // get all args
for(int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
    if(splitted[i].equalsIgnoreCase(wording)) { // checking if it's what is required
        System.out.println("Output: " + splitted[i + 1]); // should not be the last item, else you will get error. You can add if arg before to fix it
        return;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use 2 splits.

```
String word = givenStr.split("entity.")[1].split("\\.")[0];
```

Explaination:

Assuming the givenStr is "com.web.rit.entity.TestName.create"

```
givenStr.split("entity.")[1] // Get the sentence after the entity.
```

"TestName.create"

```
split("\\.")[0] // Get the string before the '.'
```

TestName

Answer (score 1):

Here's a streams solution (Java 9 minimum requirement):

```java
Optional<String> value = Arrays
     .stream("com.web.rit.entity.TestName.create".split("\\."))
     .dropWhile(s -> !s.equals("entity"))
     .skip(1)
     .findFirst();

System.out.println(value.orElse("not found"));
```